# FAFSA eligibility for international students

Tags: funding, united-states, international-students

I am Indian citizen, applying for Fall season graduate studies in the USA.

Are international students like me eligible to apply for Federal aid (FAFSA)?

Answer (score 14):

[No](http://studentaid.ed.gov/eligibility). You must be "a U.S. citizen or eligible noncitizen" (i.e., a permanent resident with a green card) to get federal student aid.

Comment: It looks like eligible non-citizen not only includes green card holders, but also some exceptional cases, see details in  [This FAFSA Page](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/eligibility/non-us-citizens).

Comment: If the attempt is to mitigate cost, *sometimes* you can speak to your department about refunding the out-of-state portion of out-of-state tuition. But I haven't the slightest clue about the requirements therein.

Answer (score -1):

NO , Federal aid is only for U.S citizens.

Even when it comes to job international can apply for only college roll positions but not work study ..

Federal aid and work study run through are like funding offered by the federal government or the countries central government thus these funds would directly allocated or redeemed by the students who are citizens .So if you are under F-1 or J-1 visa if you would want to have scholarships in u.s either your college or your department should sponsor you or if you are under grant the organisation would sponsor you.

Comment: In its present form, this answer doesn't add anything beyond what is already there in the prior answer; can you expand and provide references?

Comment: Please use the _edit_ link below your answer to incorporate all this into the answer itself instead of writing this as a comment. In SE network, comments are ephemeral, and are liable to deletion. All information deemed _important_ must be included in the answer itself.